# Fn+P hotkey conflict on HP Elitebook 830 G6?

Tags: hotkeys, hp-elitebook, numpad

I have this Elitebook 830 G5, which has an integrated numpad on JKLUIO, when Fn key is held. I Use the numpad a lot and this is a very important feature to me.
However, HP made a change and made a hotkey conflict on Fn+P: it's both * in numpad and also it triggers HP's SureView feature, which darkens the display every time I try to multiply numbers in numpad.

I have opened a ticket with HP and after three days of remote fiddling and frustration they said it's hardcoded and basically it's my fault I ordered a more expensive laptop with SureView.

Since there is no other way to fix this but get rid of the laptop, I am looking for a replacement.

So, whoever has a newer 830 G6 with SureView, can you please check if this conflict still exists?

Comment: If sureview is software, uninstall it? or other setting to disable it, did you look in the bios?

Comment: The BIOS only has an option to force the SureView to be always active (view angle of display always narrow), but no option to disable it or the hotkey Fn+P.
It can't be uninstalled, seems to be active in firmware level. I could not find a driver I could uninstall to stop it work.
And even if I disabled it, this would disable a feature that was actually paid extra for. As mentioned, I spent 3 days with HP support, installing drivers, playing with settings, etc. Now I just want to know if the same problem is present with newer model, G6.